# Systemtap effect on performance

Tags: linux, profiling, systemtap

I'm looking for some real information about the effect of systemtap on performance. I know that static kernel probes are documented somewhere on their website (with stats), but what about userspace probes?

I saw this post on their mailing list (http://sourceware.org/ml/systemtap/2009-q1/msg00518.html) which points at a possibility of single-steping in some cases. Can anyone explain / point at some resources that list which techniques are used for which probes?

What overhead will `process().function()` introduce? What about static marks?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://sourceware.org/ml/systemtap/2006-q3/msg00146.html) is some benchmarks of the overhead on a ppc64 machine. This is all I could find. It appears that SystemTap was designed to be a very low overhead tracer according to [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/315022/).

It would seem that the utrace and uprobe user-space side of SystemTap is not where most of the work is done. So it shouldn't be too much different from the kernel trace benchmarks given. Here are some [utrace performance tests](http://www.mail-archive.com/utrace-devel@redhat.com/msg00179.html).

Since the current version is only 0.8 I guess there has not been much work on quantifying the performance and overhead of SystemTap.